# React JS not working with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, reactjs

I'm trying to use React with Internet Explorer 9 but getting the following errors even trying to run something very barebones:

**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'isArray'
react-with-addons.js, line 4 character 317**

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'create'
JSXTransformer.js, line 4 character 326

I've read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html, which says IE8 might have these issues, but no mention about IE9. Googling didn't really bring up any solutions either.

Still, I tried adding es5-shim/sham as suggested on that page. That results in a different error:

**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'hasAttribute'
es5-shim.min.js, line 6 character 4143**

Has anyone encountered these errors before in IE9 or otherwise?

Thanks for the help!

The full code I'm trying to run is:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/react-with-addons.js"></script>
  <script src="js/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx">
    React.render(
    <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that JSXTransformer works outside of evergreen browsers.  It's intended for use in demos/early development.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand is right. To get the older browser support you have to bundle (browserify/webpack) as well as "envify" and uglify the bundle. It will remove the code that is only for development.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Generally, you need to include the specified polyfills for ES5 features (as you've noticed): https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#browser-support

You may also need HTML5 Shiv in addition to the the polyfills you've provided.

More specifically, though, the problem is probably not with polyfills but with the document mode IE9 is running in. You want to make sure that you are setting the correct document mode in your HTML file so IE knows which version to target. Otherwise, even though you are using IE9 it may be targeting IE7 which is no good.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 6):

In index.js file you have to add polyfill. These imports should be in the first of your import.

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';   
//other imports
```

Now open in ur ie it works.

Before import you have to install react-app-polyfill.

```
 //To install use below command:

 npm install react-app-polyfill
```

link reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill

Comment: It is a known limitation that the dev server does not support IE9/11. After adding import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9'; & import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';, try to build the project and serve the same. It will work. If you are using yarn, try the next 2 commands for serving your application build - yarn global add serve
  serve -s build

Comment: @PrijeshMeppayil didn't work even with build for me