# IE9 Object.defineProperty not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have a `Model` class and I would like to use the following to set a getter on it, but it seems to fail in IE9 but works fine in modern browsers. Any ideas why?

```
    Object.defineProperty(Model, 'propType', {
        get: function () {
            var propType = React.PropTypes.shape(config.fields);
            propType.Class = this;

            return propType;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you get an error in IE9?  Or what exactly happens?

Comment: It doesn't seem to show me a related error (it shows me later on that a call to propType returns undefined). I also cant seem to set an alert or debugger inside that get

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that `React.PropTypes.shape(config.fields);` is returning undefined in IE9? If that's the case, the statement `propType.Class = this;` would throw a `ReferenceError`, which would explain why setting an alert or debugger statement in `get` doesn't work.

If ReactJS is the problem, it might just be that you need some polyfills. React may need some ES5 polyfills to work in IE9. For more info, see:

- [React JS not working with Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29828561/5249519)
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#browser-support-and-polyfills

Hope that helps.