# Updating state with React does not update DOM in IE9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-9

I am using React and whenever I update the state of my component, it does not immediately update the view in IE9. I have to scroll the specific dom element out of my view and scroll it back into view to see it update. This works fine in all other browsers (Safari, Chrome, IE10+, Firefox)

Any idea what is causing this and how I can make it update without having to do this scrolling?

Comment: You have no error in the console ?

Comment: One answer you won't like is... stop using IE9. It's not supported by MS, and I'm surprised react even supports it. Are you making sure you're including an HTML5 polyfill?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't have the luxury to make that decision for this project unfortunately.

Comment: @SteevePitis No errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. When using a span tag around a state property in ReactJS, IE9 will not update it visually unless right-click selecting the text or scrolling it out of your view and back in.

Answer (score 1):

For IE-9 you can use like

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

or you can find same question with solution over here

[React JS not working with Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828561/react-js-not-working-with-internet-explorer-9)

It supports IE9 ,check here

[IE supported after IE9](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/12/discontinuing-ie8-support.html)

Comment: I've seen that post, the title might be the same but that user has completely different errors. I am already using what is suggested as answer there. And I am not getting any errors, my view gets updated, but only after I scroll the specific dom element out of my view and back up.